# $y''+y\ln(1+x)=x+e^x$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

[image]

**Seriously**, I have no idea about the defintion of maximal unique solution for 2nd order ODE as asked in the asked and what $J$ it is asking?

I did a lot of research about it and came across only first order ODE with maximal solutions examples on internet, which I dont understand them also. :(

Comment: how are the solutions ordered?

Comment: ask the genius who already answered an article

Comment: You said you have no idea about "maximality". So my question to you is what is the order relation on solutions. The answer by L. Lehmann doesn't cover that.

Comment: that is what i meant by that ... he didnt asnwer that thing and even i dont know what is maximlaity ... i dont understand it and never heard it that is whjy i came here

Comment: Regarding what “maximal solution” means, it's explained here, for example:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/135298/maximal-solution-of-differential-or-integral-equation-apply-it-to-fracd-ud (This was the first hit when I googled it.) If there's something there that you don't understand, perhaps you could be more specific about *what* you don't understand, so that others won't have to try in vain with the same explanations.

Comment: done send me first order DE related examples ..i wanna see 2nd order example ... do u have a link related to 2nd order ODE :)

Comment: It's the same definition!

Comment: i understood the link ... but if that is the case .. then we need to find the solution of this equation .. given which is impossible asx there is no closed form i can obtain for this DE ... i can obtain series solution i guess

Comment: If you have a task about maximal solutions, then you should also have its definition and theorems about it in your course materials. That you can transform higher order DE into first order systems should have been discussed around the discussion of the existence theorems, as they usually are only given in a first-order version. Thus you can apply everything you know about first-order systems also to higher order DE.

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to apply the theorem for the existence of a local solution of an  IVP $y'=f(x,y)$, $y(x_0)=y_0$, $f:\Bbb R\times \Bbb R^n\supset D\to\Bbb R^n$. There are two variants that can be relevant here.

> **Theorem (existence 1)** If $f$ is continuous and locally $y$-Lipschitz, then the IVP has a local solution $y:(x_0-h,x_0+h)\to\Bbb R^n$ which is unique for this interval.

This is the usually presented version with a proof that uses a straight-forward application of the Banach fixed-point theorem.

> **Theorem (existence 2)** If $D=(a,b)\times \Bbb R^n$ and $f$ is globally Lipschitz on $D$, then the IVP has a unique maximal solution $y:(a,b)\to\Bbb R^n$.

The proof of this version requires either a modified supremum norm on the space of continuous functions, or a modified fixed-point theorem.

---

To apply the given second order linear DE, you have to formulate it as a first order system $u'=Au+b$, $u=(u_0,u_1)=(y,y')$,
$$
\pmatrix{u_0'\\u_1'}=\pmatrix{0&1\\-\ln(1+x)&0}\pmatrix{u_0\\u_1}+\pmatrix{0\\x+e^x}
$$
Over each closed interval $I=[a,b]$ where $A(t),b(t)$ are continuous, this has the [$u$-Lipschitz constant](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1587871/115115) $L=\max_{x\in I}\|A(x)\|$. This then results in the [existence theorem for linear DE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2327351/115115), if $A(t),b(t)$ are continuous over the interval $(\alpha,\beta)$, then the IVP with $x_0$ in that interval also has a solution with domain $(\alpha,\beta)$. As the domain of the ODE can not contain any points of discontinuity, no solution can extend over a discontinuity of the coefficient functions.

---

On the space of solutions of an IVP, which are pairs of domain interval and solution function over it, one can introduce a semi-order by inclusion. Two solutions are comparable if the domain of one is a subset of the domain of the other. The uniqueness then implies that the first is a restriction of the second solution. Any two solutions have a glued-together solution that is superior to both.

> **Definition** The [maximal solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1590414/115115) is then the maximum of this semi-order, the solution of the IVP with the largest domain.

The main theorem to indirectly characterize a maximal solution is

> **Theorem (maximal solution and boundary of domain)** For an ODE on domain $D$ any maximal solution of an IVP leaves any compact subset $K\subset D$ inside the (open) domain.

The most common applications of this theorem are when the compact set $K$ is a box or cylinder.

---

For a scalar higher order linear DE as the given one, normalized to have leading coefficient $1$, this tells you that the maximal domain of a solution of the IVP is the maximal sub-interval of the joint domain [over which the coefficients are continuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2736373/115115) containing the initial point $x_0$. Now the maximal interval where $\ln(1+x)$ exists and is continuous is ...

---

The power series solution, inside the radius of convergence, extends naturally to a solution of the ODE over $\Bbb C$. This in turn means that also the complex singularities give bounds to the disk of convergence (in that they have to be outside). That is, the radius of convergence of the solution is the minimum of the radii of convergence of the series expansions of the coefficients of the normalized equation. These singularities are generated by the singularities of the coefficients. Fortunately the only singularity of the coefficients of the given ODE, the ones of $\ln(1+x)$, are real.

Comment: show please i dont understand

Comment: If $a$ has a singularity at $x_0$, a solution (real or complex-valued) of $y'' + a y = b$ may still extend beyond $x_0$ if it has a zero at $x_0$. Since we have $\ln(1 + x)$, a solution can't extend beyond $x = -1$ if it's real-valued. This might not be true anymore if we're allowing $\mathbb R \to \mathbb C$ solutions.

Comment: @Maxim : You might find extensions as a function, but not as a solution of an ODE. The domain of the ODE and thus any ODE solution ends at the singularity of $a$. So even if you have ODE solutions left and right of the singularity, at the singularity itself there is no ODE and thus no  ODE solution.

Comment: You're declaring it not a solution only because $-a y + b$ has a removable singularity at $x_0$ (while $y$ itself is in $C^2((x_0 - h, x_0 + h))$). When you're constructing a power series solution, the series expansion will not stop at the removable singularity. So at the very least, I claim that the argument about the radius of the series expansion is not valid (even if the conclusion is true for this particular $a$).

Comment: @Maxim : The radius of convergence of the general power series solution will be the distance to the closest singularity. There might be a basis solution that is a polynomial or has a larger radius of convergence, but in any tuple of basis solutions, at least one will have the small radius of convergence. Give a concrete example where this is not the case.

Comment: An example is $y'' - y/x = 0, \, y(1) = 0, \, y'(1) = 0$ with the solution $y = 0$. It's possible to construct an example where the general solution is regular everywhere ($y' - y/x = 0$ with the solution $y = C x$), but the question is about the specific solution with the given initial condition.

Comment: Your examples are only ODE on the set outside the vertical line $x=0$. Any function can only be a solution in one these halves of the plane. You would need an extended definition of differential equation and its solutions than the "ordinary" one to get more than that. // Note that $\ln(1+x)$ is not even defined (as real function) for $x\le -1$, so it makes no sense to discuss any extension in that region.

Comment: But this is what I was saying in my next to last comment: even if you refuse to admit $y = 0$ as the solution of $y'' - y/x = 0$ with domain $\mathbb R$, when you're constructing the power series solution (centered at $x = 1$) to the Cauchy problem with the initial conditions $y(1) = y'(1) = 0$, you get all coefficients equal to zero. The radius of convergence is infinity. So that part of the argument is not valid for arbitrary $a$.

Comment: @Maxim : Note that neither the given ODE nor its IC are homogeneous, thus the discussion of the zero solution is rather irrelevant. // Now do the same series computation and convergence radius for arbitrary initial conditions in your examples, like in the given problem. That is, construct a pair of basis solutions. If I have not missed something, the given initial conditions qualify as "arbitrary" for the ODE in the question. There is no obvious particular solution that reduces the ODE to a homogeneous one, or any other simplification of the problem.

Comment: In my opinion, my example is relevant because your answer doesn't say anything about the ODE having to be inhomogeneous and your comment is not relevant :) because I can come up with an inhomogeneous example ($y' - y/x = 1/x$ with the solution $y = C x - 1$, and if you demand a second-order ODE, I'll be able to come up with something too). This does not address my point about the power series solution extending past the singularity of $a$.

Comment: To repeat a trivial point from some comments ago: The solution of an ODE has to stay inside the domain of the ODE. Any continuation outside is not part of the ODE solution.

Comment: The question asks for the interval of convergence of "this series". You just have a power series, determined solely by its coefficients at the expansion point. You can say that since it's asked in the context of ODEs, one has to intersect its interval of convergence with the domain of the ODE. I do not think this is the intended meaning.

Answer (score 1):

If the ODE is $y'' + a y = b$ with initial conditions given at $0$ and the functions $a, b$ are continuous on an interval containing $0$, then there exists a unique solution on that interval. So there is a unique solution on $(-1, \infty)$.

Further, if $a$ and $b$ are complex analytic at $0$, the solution is also analytic at $0$. If $S$ is its power series expansion around $0$, then the radius of convergence of $S$ is not less than the distance to the nearest singularity of $a$ or $b$. So $S$ converges at least on $(-1, 1)$.

Suppose the radius of convergence is greater than $1$. Then $S$ is analytic at $-1$ and $a = (x + e^x - S'')/S$ is meromorphic at $-1$, which gives a contradiction since we have $a = \ln(x + 1)$.

The unique solution on $(-1, \infty)$ cannot be continued to $x \leq -1$ since $f(x, y) = a y$ becomes undefined. If we allow complex-valued solutions and define $f(x, 0) = 0$, then the question is more subtle because we have to rule out non-analytic $C^2$-solutions, which may satisfy the ODE on a larger interval.